# R - sqlCopyTable() in RODBC error

Tags: r, rodbc

I am new to R language. I am trying out some examples. When I tried `sqlCopyTable` command, I am encountering error, which I have described below.

I do have below `src_customer` table in SQL Server 2014,

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|   CustomerID  |   CompanyName |   ContactName |   ContactTitle    |   Address         |   City        |   Region  |   PostalCode  |   Country |   Phone       |   Fax         |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|   ALFKI       |  Alfreds Futt |  Maria Anders |   Sales Rep       |   Obere Str. 57   |   Berlin_New  |   NULL    |   12209       |   Germany |   030-0074325 |   030-0076545 |
|   ANATR       |  Ana Trujillo |  Ana Trujillo |   Owner           |   Constitución    |   México D.F. |   NULL    |   5021        |   Mexico  |   (5)555-4729 |   (5)555-3745 |
|   ANTON       |  Antonio      |  Antonio      |   Owner           |   Mataderos  2312 |   México D.F. |   NULL    |   5023        |   Mexico  |   (5)555-3932 |   NULL        |
|   AROUT       |  Around Horn  |  Thomas Hardy |   Sales Rep       |   120 Hanover Sq. |   London      |   NULL    |   WA1 1DP     |   UK      |   (5)555-3923 |   (5)555-3923 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+
```

And the table structure is

[image]

Now when i try to copy the table data into another table `target_customer` in the same Database which has the same structure as `src_customer` table, I am getting error.

Below is the command that I have used

`sqlCopyTable(sqlConnect,srctable = "src_customer", desttable = "target_customer")`

I am getting below error

[image]

There are some `NULL` values in the table, I tried updating those columns with some value and ran the same above query. But still getting the same error.

I tried `sqlCopy` like below

`sqlCopy(sqlConnect,"SELECT * FROM Vignesh.dbo.src_customer;", "target_customer")`

`sqlCopy` worked perfectly.

What could be the issue with `sqlCopyTable` command?

**UPDATE As per @ErrantBard suggestion in the comments.**

I have created a table with single table like below

[image]

And the data in this table is

[image]

Now when I run the below R sqlCopyTable command, there is no error.

[image]

with verbose and Error info

[image]

the command is `sqlCopyTable(sqlConnect,"dbo.customer1","dbo.customer2")`

**But the target table does not have any data.**

[image]

I am totally confused with this command. **Why still this command is not working?**

Comment: Isn't it "dbo.src_customer"? instead of "src_customer"?

Comment: @ErrantBard I have tried both the thing. But nothing worked.

Comment: Hmm - then I can't help you. Some problem with the data perhaps, you could try it with a simple table (one row, one column or something like that) to try to track down the problem

Comment: @ErrantBard I have created a new table with single column and did the same again. This time I did not get any error. But there is no data copied to target table.

Comment: Try to add the verbose and errors options as well, it might give more hints

Comment: @ErrantBard I have tried with the options `verbose` and `error`. I have included the image.

Comment: It seems to me, according to verbose that your creating an empty table? So the result seems correct, even if that is not what we're expecting from the command. Any reason you can't use SQLcopy instead? (I do share your confusion)

Comment: @ErrantBard `sqlCopy` is working perfectly. I am learning R language. I stuck with this `sqlCopyTable` command. The behavior that I noticed with `sqlCopy` and `sqlCopyTable` is, it creates the table first then copies the data. If the table is already created then it throws error that `table already exist`. Really thanks for your effort.